# How to docker exec a shell builtin of docker container specifically on Ubuntu docker image/container

Tags: linux, ubuntu, docker, dockerfile, fedora

thank you for reading my post.

**Problem:**

```
# docker ps
CONTAINER ID        IMAGE                  COMMAND             
35c8b832403a        ubuntu1604:1   "sh -c /bin/sh"    

# docker exec -i -t 35c8b832403a type type
rpc error: code = 2 desc = oci runtime error: exec failed: container_linux.go:262: starting container process caused "exec: \"type\": executable file not found in $PATH"

# Dockerfile
FROM ubuntu:16.04

ENV PATH=/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin
RUN apt-get update && apt-get -y upgrade
ENTRYPOINT ["sh", "-c"]
CMD ["/bin/bash"]
```

**Description:**

My objective is to get "type" shell builtin been execute in a way of writing docker exec as below

docker exec -i -t 35c8b832403a type type (FAILED)

**NOT**

docker exec -i -t 35c8b832403a sh -c "type type" (PASSED)

I have googling around, do some modification in the container (change /etc/profile, /etc/environment, bashrc) but failed.

From the docker documentation itself, it has state that:

> COMMAND will run in the default directory of the container. It the
>   underlying image has a custom directory specified with the WORKDIR
>   directive in its Dockerfile, this will be used instead.
>
> COMMAND should be an executable, a chained or a quoted command will
>   not work. Example: docker exec -ti my_container "echo a && echo
>   b" will not work, but docker exec -ti my_container sh -c "echo a &&
>   echo b" will.

But seem it **IS POSSIBLE** when I able to get the right output **FROM DOCKER FEDORA** (Dockerfile: FROM fedora:25)

```
# docker ps
CONTAINER ID        IMAGE                  COMMAND             
2a17b2338518        fedora25:1   "sh -c /bin/sh" 

# docker exec -i -t 2a17b2338518 type type
type is a shell builtin
```

**Question:**

Is there any way to enable this on Ubuntu docker? Image/Container tweaks? Vagrantfile Configuration? Please help.

**Others:**

Using docker run, I able to get the right output because of the "ENTRYPOINT" in the Dockerfile. However **the image need to be save instead of export**.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just in case, to be able to execute type as you expect, it would need to be part of the path. Being a shell builtin wouldn't help because as you said, you don't want to execute `/bin/bash -c 'type type'`

If you want to have `type` executed as a builtin shell command, this means you need to execute a shell `/bin/bash` or `/bin/sh` and then execute 'type type' on it, making it `/bin/bash -c 'type type'`

After all, as @Henry said, docker exec is a the full command that will be executed and there is no place for `CMD` or `ENTRYPOINT` on it.

Comment: Correct me if I was wrong... do you mean it is impossible to use `docker exec "type type"` only, instead I still need to include /bin/{bash,sh} -c to execute that `docker exec "/bin/bash -c type type"`. How come Fedora image/container able to support this?? I have further check in the Fedora image/container for type, they have /bin/type which written in shell with `buildin type "$@"`, unfortunately there is no /bin created for buildin which will still throw the same error but this time it's complain about buildin was not there.

Comment: Too bad for me. The use case problem is to use `docker exec` with the argument `type type`

Comment: As I said, if you want to execute `type type`, a binary called `type` should exist in the path. There is no other way. And taking into account that type is a shell builtin, and that I haven't found a way to have an specific binary just for that, I would say your only way it to generate a script in the path with such name to trigger the shell command.

Answer (score 0):

CMD and ENTRYPOINT are meaningless if you run `docker exec`. The remaining arguments are taken as the command and executed inside the already existing container.

Maybe you wanted to use `docker run`?

Comment: Too bad for me. The use case problem is to use `docker exec` with the argument `type type`